# I get undefined for this function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the filter function to build a new array that provides only string values that are less than 10 in length. The function is however producing undefined values.

```
let move = (strings) => {
  console.log('I got here');
  let special = strings.length < 10;
  if (special) {
    console.log(strings);
    return strings;
  }
  console.log(strings);
};

const username = [];

const validUserNames = (username) => {
  username.filter(move);
};
```

//The code is expected to be called like this

//validUserNames(["Paul", "Barnabas", "Timothy", "Judas Iscariot"])

//Expected results: Paul, Barnabas, Timothy

Comment: What do you mean "producing undefined values"?

Comment: It looks like you're not using filter properly. You should read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: It producing the result undefined even though it compiles well without errors

Comment: well you never return anything so it is undefined.... So it appears to be working exactly as coded.

Comment: I guess your just calling it like `validUserNames()` and expecting username param in the function to inherit the outer username?

Comment: I actually tried using an array on it. Username is supposed to just serve as an argument for the function telling it what to expect

Comment: I returned strings in the if block

Answer (score 1):

In the `move` function, you need to return a boolean. Change it as follows :

```
let move = (string) => {
  console.log('I got here');
  let special = string.length < 10;
  if (special) {
    console.log(string);
    return special;
  }
  console.log(string);
};
```

I have changed a few other things.

The function takes a single value in as `filter` goes through the array, so I changed `strings` to `string`.

Technically, it could be reduced to this.

```
let move = (string) => {
  return string.length < 10;
};
```

I think there is also something else you aren't understanding. Having this code doesn't do anything.

```
const validUserNames = (usernames) => {
  usernames.filter(move);
}

validUserNames(["Paul", "Barnabas", "Timothy", "Judas Iscariot"]);
```

Firstly, `usernames.filter` doesn't do anything to the `usernames` array, it returns the result of the filter.
Secondly, because you are not returning this result of the filter, `validUserNames` doesn't return anything.
Thirdly, unless you store the result of validUserNames in a variable, nothing will change in the state of the application.

I suggest you change the above to this.

```
const validUserNames = usernames.filter(move);
```

`validUserNames` will then store the array of strings with a length less than 10.

Comment: There is not enough code and no explanation of what is 'expected' to help any further, @MOSESAMAECHI. Please include the code detailing how the `validUserNames` function is called and detail what the expected behavior is.

Comment: I just edited it now, integrating your opinion

Comment: What result do you get now?

Comment: undefined is my current result

Comment: @MOSESAMAECHI I hope the new change to my answer is what you are wanting. Your code and explanation is still a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Thankyou so very much Will Walsh, just implemented your idea and it has finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct solution. This function will take in any array of strings and will return string values that are lesser than 10 in length.

```
let move = (strings)=>{
        console.log('I got here');
        let special = strings.length < 10;
        if(special){
        console.log(strings);
        return strings;
        }
};
const username = [];
const validUserNames = (username)=>{let next = username.filter(move);
return next;
};
```